# Key binding for "New View into File"

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like to customize a key binding for "New View into File" (that appears in the "File" menu) in Sublime Text 3, but I can't figure out what to set for `command` :

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+v"], "command": "???"}
```

According to https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands, I would expect `clone`, but it doesn't seem to work, nor a few other expressions that I tried.

Who knows the trick?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The command you are looking for is `clone_file`**.

You can see the commands asociated to sublime menus (main menu, side bar context menu, etc) inside the files with extension *.sublime-menu* located inside *Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package*. In this case the main menu file name is *Main.sublime-menu*.

Usually I find this [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/commands.html)  better and more complete than the original, it includes this command.

Answer (score 7):

to find what command that is doing it, you open the console

```
ctrl + `
View > Show Console
```

and type/paste "sublime.log_commands(True)"

```
sublime.log_input(True)     # start logging input
sublime.log_input(False)    # stop logging input
sublime.log_commands(True)  # start commands input
sublime.log_commands(False) # stop commands input
```

here is output from to commands

> command: left_delete
>
> command: show_overlay {"overlay": "command_palette"}

if you want to set a new keyboard shortcut

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+v"], "command": "left_delete"}
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "left_delete", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette" }}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by navigating to `Sublime Text` --> `Preferences` --> `Key Bindings`

[image: <code>Sublime Text</code> --> <code>Preferences</code> --> <code>Key Bindings</code>]

and then adding the line

`{ "keys": ["super+shift+x"], "command": "clone_file" }`

to the `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file  that Sublime Text 3 opens for you when you click `Key Bindings`

my `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file now looks like this

[image]

now I save my `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file and voila, `cmd+shift+x` now opens a `New View into File`

(a note - the `super` key in this Sublime Text 3 key binding maps to the `cmd` key on the Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate the menu to key bindings:

```
Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings
```

Two files, side by side, will open. The file on the right is for user settings. Add the following line:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+n"], "command": "clone_file"}
```

I am using ***ctrl+shift+n***, but you can replace it with whatever shortcut you wish